# fs.writeFileSync writing blank file

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am using fs for writing a pdf file to disk, the pdf file contains 7 pages which have contents, however when the file is getting written it doesn't have any content in it. The whole file is blank. Below is the code I am using for this

```
request.get({
        url: spConfig.host + spConfig.sitecollection + '_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(\'/sites/MSDS/Construction/ProductLabels/SD32382_-_ADVA Cast 596_(B2).pdf\')/$value',
        headers: headers,
        json: true
    }).then(response => {
      console.log('Inside Success')
      // console.log(response)
      // let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname+'/wsdl/attachment.pdf')
      console.log(response.length)
       try {
            fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+'/wsdl/attachment.pdf', response,'binary')
            console.log('File has been written successfully')
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error in writing file')
            console.log(err)
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        spResponseCount = spResponseCount + 1  
        reject(err)
    })
```

Comment: you can't use callback in writeFileSync, callback is for async write

Comment: response, what type is it? (String,array)

Comment: response is of type binary, it is a pdf file byte stream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a mixup between the `fs.writeFileSync`, `fs.writeSync` and the `fs.writeFile`.

Try with this:

```
try {
    fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+'/wsdl/attachment.pdf', response);
    console.log('Success in writing file')
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error in writing file')
    console.log(err)
}
```

If the result is not what you expect, you should give a check to the content of the `response` variable and make sure that it's properly filled.

References:

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options

---

I've tried to recreate your code but I'm not sure what library you're using to extract data. This example works fine with me:

```
let request = require('request-promise');
let fs = require('fs');

request.get({
    url: 'http://che.org.il/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pdf-sample.pdf',
    encoding: null
})
.then(response => {

    try {
      fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+'/attachment.pdf', response);
      console.log('Success in writing file')
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error in writing file')
      console.log(err)
    }
});
```

EDIT:

My code was not working properly because I forgot to set the encoding to null. In the documentation of the request, there's this explanation:

> encoding - encoding to be used on setEncoding of response data. If
>   null, the body is returned as a Buffer. Anything else (including the
>   default value of undefined) will be passed as the encoding parameter
>   to toString() (meaning this is effectively utf8 by default). (Note: if
>   you expect binary data, you should set encoding: null.)

From https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#request-options-callback

The encoding of the `writeFileSync` can be safely dropped.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. The file is getting written the control falls in the try block and i am getting the log as `Success in writing file`, however the file is still blank.

Comment: add a `console.log(response, response.length);` before the `writeFileSync`. I think it'd be better if you add how you fill `response` in your question because I think you're having an unfulfilled Promise (or something like that).

Comment: I have updated the complete code in the actual question for your reference. Please have a look and the response.length prints `96979` in the console.

Comment: Can you check if you're not having the content you're looking for in `response.data`?

Comment: response.data is undefined, however the response has the data. Does the response should contain the data or the response.data should contain the data?

Comment: The response probably has the whole http response (which has been converted in json before, if I read it right). The data you want is stored somewhere else. Anyway it depends on what kind of library you use to extract data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159488/discussion-between-jeet-and-stefano).